# What is a nuclear spin system?

Tags: solid-state-physics, quantum-spin

> Several years ago, Pound, Purcell, and Ramsey studied experimentally various properties of the nuclear spin system in a pure LiF crystal for which spin lattice relaxation times were as large as 5 minutes at room temperature, while the spin-spin relaxation time was less than $10^{-5}$ second.

*From "Thermodynamics and Statistical Mechanics at Negative Absolute Temperature" by Norman F. Ramsey.  Phys. Rev. 103, 20 – Published 1 July 1956.*

*Nuclear spin* is the total angular momentum of a nucleus. But what is a *nuclear spin **system***?

Answer (score 1):

Without a reference to the source of the "nuclear spin system" usage in a crystal lattice, I would hazard a guess that what they are talking about is something like a diamond with some fraction of the lattice sites occupied by the $C^{13}$ isotope instead of $C^{12}$.  The spin of the $C^{12}$ nucleus is zero while the extra neutron in $C^{13}$ yields a nuclear spin of $\frac{1}{2}$. The collection of $C^{13}$ sites would then be called a nuclear spin system.  Other odd-nucleon isotopes could be envisioned that would play a similar role in a crystal lattice.  Such systems have been considered for applications in quantum computing.